# Use xargs and awk to print out free/total disk

Tags: centos

I came across one script to check server and found this.

```
df -h | xargs | awk '{print "Free/total disk: " $11 " / " $9}'
free -m | xargs | awk '{print "Free/total memory: " $17 " / " $8 " MB"}'
```

I don't really understand why it's $11, $9, $17, $8 value and why they used xargs. Could someone clarify about this? 
Btw, here is the output of dh -h command on my terminal.

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 07-04-2016]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       20G  3.4G   17G  17% /
```

Comment: They used `xargs` because they didn't have much of a clue about what they were doing, and possibly even less of a clue about how to use tools like `df` and `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any parameters, `xargs` splits its input into words and outputs them, separated by single spaces:

```
echo -e a  b\\nc | xargs
```

gives

```
a b c
```

So piping `df`'s output through `xargs` collapses it into a single line, which is then split again by `awk` here.

The `$n` tokens are replaced with the *n*th word; counting words in your example output (and in the output of `free -m`) shows the correspondence.

`xargs` could be avoided here by instructing `awk` to only look at the second line of its input. Also, the `-P` option should be used with `df` here to avoid splitting long device names.

Comment: Ah i got it. Thank you so much for a detailed answer.